# in HTML Call href="#" automatically?

Tags: href

Can the following href="#" be called automatically?

```
<a id="loadBtn" href="#">Do stuff</a></p>
```

Thanks!

(Update) In the following facebook gallery launcher:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.getfacebookalbums.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.getfacebookalbums.css" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#loadBtn').click(function () {
                    $('#albumsContainer').getFacebookAlbums({
                        appId : 'ID',
                        onImageSelected : function (data) {
                            alert("Your facebook image is located at " + data);
                            window.location.href = "assignFacebookPhoto.php?fbPhoto=" + data; 
                        }
                    })
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                font-family: Arial, _sans;
                font-size: 0.8em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p><a id="loadBtn" href="#">Get photo</a></p>


        <div id="albumsContainer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Essentially to get to the action faster rather than having msc bits of text to click first.

Comment: You might want to explain what you mean in more detail, as it's not clear what `call href="#" automatically` means.

Answer (score 0):

you can set href attribute with whatever value you want as per below code:

```
$('#loadBtn').attr('href','#');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether the href='#' is just for example purposes or what you're putting in your final code.

(1) If you want to scroll to the top of the page, you can either use $('body').scrollTop(0) or animate it a bit with something like $('html, body').animate( {scrollTop : 0 }, 200);  (If you want to animate it, just attach it to #loadBtn's click event and be sure to return false, so the anchor won't jump to the top and override your animation.)

If you want, you can also set window.location.hash so the hash location will be recorded.

(2) If you want to simulate a click on the link, you can use .trigger(), e.g.: $('#loadBtn').trigger('click');

Answer (score 0):

I think following code will work for you:

```
$("#loadBtn").ready(function(){
 $(this).click();
});
```

Also try this in your onload function:

```
document.getElementById('yourLinkID').click(); 
// Automatically href will be called
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your pointers. It lead me to the idea of just rearranging the javascript so that the code was executed without need to click anything:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.getfacebookalbums.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.getfacebookalbums.css" type="text/css">

        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                font-family: Arial, _sans;
                font-size: 0.8em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!--p><a id="loadBtn" href="#">Get photo</a></p-->



        <div id="albumsContainer"></div>



        <script type="text/javascript">


            $('#albumsContainer').getFacebookAlbums({
                        appId : 'ID',
                        onImageSelected : function (data) {
                            alert("Your facebook image is located at " + data);
                            window.location.href = "assignFacebookPhoto.php?fbPhoto=" + data; 
                        }
                    })



        </script>



    </body>
</html>
```